# Extend a class of a plugin

Tags: php, actions, oop

There is a plugin that uses a class; and create an object like this:

```
class WC_Disability_VAT_Exemption {

    public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', array( $this, 'exemption_field' ) );
    }

    public function exemption_field() {
        //some code here
    }

}

/**
 * Return instance of WC_Disability_VAT_Exemption.
 *
 * @since 1.3.3
 *
 * @return WC_Disability_VAT_Exemption
 */
function wc_dve() {
    static $instance;

    if ( ! isset( $instance ) ) {
        $instance = new WC_Disability_VAT_Exemption();
    }

    return $instance;
}

wc_dve();
```

I want to extend the class because I want to use this method to remove an action:

```
class WC_Disability_VAT_Exemption_Extend extends WC_Disability_VAT_Exemption {

    function __construct() {
        $this->unregister_parent_hook();
        add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', array( $this, 'exemption_field' ) );
    }

    function unregister_parent_hook() {
        global $instance;
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', array( $instance, 'exemption_field' ) );
    }

    function exemption_field() {
        //---some code here
    }
}
```

But `global $instance` doesn't get the class object. It returns *null*. So how can I get `$instance` object in the extended class?

Comment: Your first question's answer is been given. Secondly I don't see you've extended any class here.

Answer (score 3):

Woocommerce support sent me the solution of my problem:

```
function unregister_parent_hook() {
  if ( function_exists( 'wc_dve' ) ) {
    $instance = wc_dve();
   remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', array( $instance, 'exemption_field' ) );
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you used [`static`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) key word inside the first function. The keyword `static` will not make the variable `global`. It'll make sure that the variable exists only in that local function scope, but it does not lose its value when program execution leaves this scope.

So if you try to access in the second function the `global $my_class;` it'll obviously return `null`. Cause ***PHP*** will treat the `global $my_class;` in the second function as a new global variable just declared.

Hope that helps.

Comment: The problem is that the plugin is made by woocommerce and I want to extend it because I want to remove an action.
So, should I talk with woocomerce?

Comment: Would be better if you give the class `a()` full code here.

Comment: Take a look. I edit the main code above